# Waiting 24 hours to Kasher

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher

When someone kashers a utensil, a 24 hour waiting period is required.

Is the 24 hour wait after the last use or after it is washed?

Comment: How do you know such a period is required?

Comment: @chofetz Chaim generally speaking you wait until it’s cleaned and dry then 24hours. However it some instances you can go straight to kasher after it been cleaned and dried. Again CYLOR!

Comment: CYLOR. There's an assortment of minhagim, ranging from 24 hours before cleaning to cleaning and then 24 hours to 24 hours after last use to 24 hours after last washed to no wait required depending on the type of kashering and what it's being kashered from, etc. etc. I'm VTCing as unclear until you can provide a bit more basis as to what, specifically, you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

your question is more of a question understanding a rule called noten tam lifgam

If you look at the last 2 daf of Tractate Avodah Zara it would seem from there that it would go from 24 hours after it was used and not washed.

my proof look at the shulchan aruch on it but the much more complicated reasoning will be in the comments

Comment: A rosh yeshiva from Eretz Yisrael said that you can look at the machloket between Rashi and tosafost  theer in two ways. Does the kli depend on how it was used for tefilat kelim or what the majority of the kli is? This idea os found in the meiri there. From here we see that everything relies on the kli itself. based on this we can understand a concept in kashrus. Ben Yomo And Eino Ben Yomo. these two concepts are used heavily with a concept called notem tam lifgam.

Comment: from the tosafost who holds taht it depends on how it was used teaches us if one must wait the 24 hours or not. if we hold like the majority then if all that is needed is tefilat keilim, then your question is void. according to tosafost  Since it's noten tam lifgam that would not rely on cleaning itself. that is all derived from the gemara using a machloket between rash and tosafost.

Comment: being said a little simpler. Noten tam lifgam is based on the using of the object itself , not the actual cleaning